# Сортировка сообщений

Tags: mysql

Необходимо отсортировать последние сообщения у пользователя. Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT * 
       FROM `chat` 
       WHERE `to` = 6 
          OR `from` = 6 
       ORDER BY `id` DESC ) as msg 
GROUP BY chat_id
```

Но почему-то результат приходит в не отсортированном виде

Comment: Не "почему-то", а потому, что в запросе отсутствует ORDER BY. А тот, что в подзапросе - само собой, игнорируется. Ну и плюс неполная группировка, вследствие чего результат недетерминирован.

Comment: @Akina, не совсем понял вас. Если я пишу так( так по мне глупость полная): `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `to` = 6 OR `from` = 6 ORDER BY `id` DESC ) as msg GROUP BY chat_id ORDER BY `id` DESC` .Ничего не происходит

Comment: И как понять "неполная группировка"?

Comment: *как понять "неполная группировка"?* После группировки по chat_id - для каждого из chat_id остальные поля в итоговой записи (там же есть другие поля, верно?) получат одно из значений в группе с этим chat_id - причём случайное. Ну и какой смысл в таком "результате"? Собственно именно поэтому и `ORDER BY \`id\`` даёт чёрт те что...

Comment: @Akina, но я ведь не могу сделать `GROUP BY id, chat_id` если мне нужно группировать только по одному параметру

Comment: И как вообще может игнорироваться подзапрос, если я как бы создаю временную таблицу и уже ее группирую. Ничего не понятно(

Comment: *как вообще может игнорироваться подзапрос* Игнорируется не подзапрос, а сортировка в нём. *но я ведь не могу сделать* Всё, что Вы можете сделать (и должны были сделать с самого начала) - это ПОЛНОСТЬЮ описАть задачу, со всеми тонкостями и оговорками, и показать структуру исходной таблицы (а ещё лучше -создать fiddle с тестовыми данными). Ибо догадываться, что же на самом деле нужно - занятие неблагодарное.